# Is Windows SDK always needed for including Windows.h?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include

I tried to use FindFirstFile WIN API function in my c program and noticed that i can use it after including Windows.h in Visual Studio 2010. I am a bit confused because i never installed the Windows SDK on that system. I thought one can only use Windows.h after installing the Windows SDK. Can someone explain to me why this is possible? Also i am wondering about the starting capital Letter of Windows.h. In the past i used windows.h. I have to do a presentation of my code on a computer with only Visual Studio 2010 installed and need to be sure that it will compile on that computer. Big thanks for any helpful information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows SDK isn't the only way to get the headers - they are also included with Visual Studio.

> Visual C++ and the Windows Header Files
>
> Microsoft Visual C++ includes copies of the Windows header files that
>   were current at the time Visual C++ was released. Therefore, if you
>   install updated header files from an SDK, you may end up with multiple
>   versions of the Windows header files on your computer. If you do not
>   ensure that you are using the latest version of the SDK header files,
>   you will receive the following error code when compiling code that
>   uses features that were introduced after Visual C++ was released:
>   error C2065: undeclared identifier.

Source: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Comment: That answered it perfectly. Thank you very much.